# Multiple join tables between 2 tables with Symfony

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, annotations

I'd like to create multiple relations between the same tables

```
Project <--> ProjectManagers <--> Employees
Project <--> ProjectEmployees <--> Employees
```

I already have a Project and Employees entity.
How do I make the connections with annotations?

Already tried the Many-To-Many, Bidirectional relation. But doctrine will generate 1 join table but need a projects_managers table aswell.

```
<?php
/** @Entity */
class Project
{
    // ...

    /**
     * Many Projects have Many Employees.
     * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Employee", inversedBy="projects")
     * @JoinTable(name="projects_employees")
     */
    private $employees;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->employees = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    // ...
}

/** @Entity */
class Employee
{
    // ...
    /**
     * Many Employees have Many Projects.
     * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Project", mappedBy="employees")
     */
    private $projects;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->projects = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Could you just add a field to Employee to specify whether they are a ProjectManager or ProjectEmployee? Assuming they can't be both at the same time...

Comment: You will need to create ProjectManagers and ProjectEmployees entities and then establish one to many relations as needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't you create the two tables as look-up tables and then create the relationships? For example create a ProjectManagers entity with the fields id, project_id, and employee_id. Same for ProjectEmployees. For ProjectManagers entity you'd create a one-to-many from Projects to ProjectManagers. The same for the Employees entity. If you setup your relationships correctly you could then do something like this in your controller:

```
$project = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository( 'AppBundle:Projects' )->findById( $id );
$employees = $project->getProjectManagers()->getEmployees();
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know this is not possible. I know three alternatives for you:

a) Let ProjectManagers and ProjectEmployees extend the base class ProjectMembers and use table inheritance. (Nice article: https://blog.liip.ch/archive/2012/03/27/table-inheritance-with-doctrine.html)

b) Make a property $projectManagers and $projectEmployees in the Employees entity so that the relations got separated. (You could write an additional function in your entity that merge both arrays for you)

c) Make a many-to-many Unidirectional relation so that Employees does not know about the reverse entities.

Goed weekend :-)